# How to move a blob document from one container to another with metadata from azure function?

Tags: blob, azure-functions

I am trying to copy a blob document from one container to another along with the metadata. I have tried the following code from azure function but getting error mentioned in the code.

HTTP Request:

```
{
   "SourceUrl": "https://devstorage.blob.core.windows.net/test-docs/123.jpeg",
   "DestinationUrl": "https://devstorage.blob.core.windows.net/test-docs-completed/123.jpeg"
}
```

Azure Function Code:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    string reqAsString = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MoveProcessedDocumentRequest blobCopyRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MoveProcessedDocumentRequest>(reqAsString);

    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockSource = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobCopyRequest.SourceUrl));
    await cloudBlockSource.FetchAttributesAsync();

    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlockDestinationContainer = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobCopyRequest.DestinationUrl)).Container;
    string name = cloudBlockSource.Uri.Segments.Last();
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockDestination;
    cloudBlockDestination = cloudBlockDestinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);

    // Copy metadata
    foreach (var meta in cloudBlockSource.Metadata)
    {
        cloudBlockDestination.Metadata.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(meta.Key, meta.Value));
    }

    await cloudBlockDestination.StartCopyAsync(cloudBlockSource);
    // Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: The specified resource does not exist.

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your code with `CloudBlobContainer` instance.

Change:

```
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlockDestinationContainer = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobCopyRequest.DestinationUrl)).Container;
```

To:

```
var uri = new Uri("blobCopyRequest.DestinationUrl");
var storage = new StorageCredentials("your account name", "your storage key");
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlockDestinationContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(uri, storage);
```

And the DestinationUrl is destcontainer url.

HTTP Request:

```
{
   "SourceUrl": "https://devstorage.blob.core.windows.net/test-docs/123.jpeg",
   "DestinationUrl": "https://devstorage.blob.core.windows.net/test-docs-completed"
}
```